# How to type properly object initial value in React CreateContext

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

How should I type properly in React Create Context initial value of constance trainsDetails which is an object with different properties. TrainsDetails is a single object fetched from end-point with values provided below in type TrainsDetailsResponseType:

```
type TrainsDetailsResponseType = {
    trainId: string;
    trainNo: string;
    lineId: string;
    route: string;
    lineKmPosition: string;
    speed: number;
    deviationFromTimetable: number;
    mileage: number;
    lastInspectionDate: string;
    nextInspectionDate: string;
    state: string;
};
```

Here is the interface of TrainsContextValues:

```
interface TrainsContextValues {
    trainsList: TrainsListResponseType[];
    trainsDetails: TrainsDetailsResponseType;
    handlePushToTrainsDetails: (arg: string) => void;
    trainId: string;
}
```

How should I type propely initial value of trainsDetails ?

```
export const TrainsContext = createContext<TrainsContextValues>({
    trainsList: [],
    trainsDetails: ,
    handlePushToTrainsDetails: () => undefined,
    trainId: '',
});
```

Here You can see also how I typed trainsDetails in useState hook

```
 const [trainsDetails, setTrainsDetails] = useState<TrainsDetailsResponseType>();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in your example, the state value type is `TrainsDetailsResponseType | undefined`:

```
// typeof trainsDetails = TrainsDetailsResponseType | undefined
const [trainsDetails, setTrainsDetails] = useState<TrainsDetailsResponseType>();
```

You can specify a similar type for `trainsDetails` in the React context value:

```
interface TrainsContextValues {
  trainsList: TrainsListResponseType[];

  // optional type (?) or TrainsDetailsResponseType | undefined
  trainsDetails?: TrainsDetailsResponseType;

  handlePushToTrainsDetails: (arg: string) => void;
  trainId: string;
}

export const TrainsContext = React.createContext<TrainsContextValues>({
  trainsList: [],
  trainsDetails: undefined,
  handlePushToTrainsDetails: () => undefined,
  trainId: "",
});
```

This is correct, since you really don't have the data for `trainsDetails` until you fetched it from end-point.

---

**UPDATED. LONG ANSWER**

It is important that the argument that you pass to `createContext` is not the `initialValue` of the context, it is the `defaultValue`. The `defaultValue` argument is only used when a component does not have a matching Provider above it in the tree.

You have two scenarios for using context:

**1.** - You allow the context to be used until all the necessary data is received. In this case, you should provide a fallback if there is no data:

```
interface TrainsContextValues {
  trainsList: TrainsListResponseType[];
  trainsDetails?: TrainsDetailsResponseType;
  handlePushToTrainsDetails: (arg: string) => void;
  trainId: string;
}

export const TrainsContext = React.createContext<TrainsContextValues>({
  trainsList: [],
  trainsDetails: undefined,
  handlePushToTrainsDetails: () => {},
  trainId: "",
});

const Parent = () => {
  const [trainsDetails, setTrainsDetails] =
    useState<TrainsDetailsResponseType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTrainsDetail = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("your-api");
        const data: TrainsDetailsResponseType = await response.json();

        setTrainsDetails(data);
      } catch {
        // your logic for the failed request
      }
    };

    getTrainsDetail();
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // undefined | data from api
      trainsDetails,

      // replace to actually
      trainsList: [],
      handlePushToTrainsDetails: () => {},
      trainId: "",
    }),
    [trainsDetails]
  );

  return (
    <TrainsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Child />
    </TrainsContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const { trainsDetails } = useContext(TrainsContext);

  // technically, the component can be rendered out of context and it should be ready for this
  if (!trainsDetails) {
    return <FallbackComponent />;
  }

  return <TrainsDetailsComponent data={trainsDetails} />;
};
```

**2.** - You do not allow the use of context without real data. **WARNING** - this is a very strict mode, it is used only when the application **cannot** and **should not** use the context without real data:

```
interface TrainsContextValues {
  trainsList: TrainsListResponseType[];
  trainsDetails: TrainsDetailsResponseType;
  handlePushToTrainsDetails: (arg: string) => void;
  trainId: string;
}

export const TrainsContext = React.createContext<TrainsContextValues | null>(
  null
);

const useTrainsContext = (): TrainsContextValues => {
  const data = useContext(TrainsContext);

  if (!data) {
    throw new Error("could not find trains context value");
  }

  return data;
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [trainsDetails, setTrainsDetails] =
    useState<TrainsDetailsResponseType>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTrainsDetail = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("your-api");
        const data: TrainsDetailsResponseType = await response.json();

        setTrainsDetails(data);
      } catch {
        // your logic for the dropped request
      }
    };

    getTrainsDetail();
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () =>
      trainsDetails
        ? {
            trainsDetails,
            trainsList: [],
            handlePushToTrainsDetails: () => {},
            trainId: "",
          }
        : null,
    [trainsDetails]
  );

  if (!contextValue) {
    // some fallback for empty trainsDetails
    return <Loading />;
  }

  return (
    <TrainsContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      <Child />
    </TrainsContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Child = () => {
  const { trainsDetails } = useTrainsContext();

  return <TrainsDetailsComponent data={trainsDetails} />;
};
```

The second scenario is specific and is used only when missing of data in the context is a logical error in the composition of components. And a user is not able to correct this situation. For example, missing of a store provider in redux.

Comment: Hello, thanks. When I put Your comments I get also typescript error when I want to extract specific prop from object trainsDetails. It's in the component where data is used: 

Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
const trainsDetails: TrainsDetailsResponseType | undefined

Comment: @marcinb1986 Hello! I have updated the answer. Please take a look, I hope it will be useful for you.